# Dynamic array of abstract class

Tags: c++, arrays, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class called `CBase` and two other classes `CDerived1` and `CDerived2` that are derived from `CBase`.

How would I now create a dynamic array (i.e. add and delete elements at runtime) of `CBase`? Of course, this array would just contain objects of the derived classes because the base class is abstract.

I would try something like this:

```
CBase* arr;
arr = (CBase*) malloc(arrSize*sizeof(CBase));
```

It feels like this solution would get complicated when I want to resize the array as I want. How would I do that? Or do you recommend any other kind of array for that?

Comment: (a) manual dynamic memory management in modern C++ = terrible idea. (b) using `malloc` to accomplish (a) even *more* terrible idea. Use an appropriate container of smart pointers.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this. I would highly recommend you get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read it very carefully.

Comment: 1) You're using `malloc` when `new` is much better (malloc does not call c'tors). 2) You're using manual memory management when standard containers or `unique_ptr` are much better 3) You cannot have an array of polymorphic objects.  That will lead to object slicing. You need another level of indirection.

Comment: I believe the tool you should be reaching for is `vector<unique_ptr<CBase>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an array of `CBase` objects, so it will suffer from [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) when you try to assign derived objects to the array elements. What you really need is an array of `CBase*` pointers instead:

```cpp
CBase** arr;
arr = new CBase*[arrSize];

arr[0] = new CDerived1;
...

for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)
    delete arr[i];
delete [] arr;
```

That being said, you really should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`, and in C++11 and later, prefer `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CBase>> arr;
arr.reserve(arrSize);

arr.push_back(std::unique_ptr<CBase>(new CDerived1));
// or, in C++14 and later:
// arr.push_back(std::make_unique<CDerived1>());
...

//no manual cleanup needed!
```